# How do you update a keycloak custom user storage provider jar that includes a version number?

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a User Storage Provider jar that I wrote to use our corporate sin in databse from keycloak which I wrote when using keycloak 19.0.2. I have since updated keycloak to 24.0.4 and had to update the user storage provider jar. When I did so, I updated the version number, which is also in the name of the jar.

However, I am now unable to use the new jar as keycloak's build process complains that the old jar is not found and crashes :(

I have had to symlink the new jar to the old name to get keycloak to build and start, how do I get around this limitation?